# Elastic Search Lucene version error

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a very simple ES Client which will send a query to local ES server(1.4.1 version of ES) and get the results and display to the user. Now, I took this code to a different project X and tried to use it along with X because I need some APIs from X. 
Now, when I run the same code when i am in X, then I get this error and don't know how to resolve. Can you please help me with this.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_3_6

```
at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:45) 
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:136) 
at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159) 
at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166) 
at org.bmi.elasticsearch.ranking.TestClass2.main(TestClass2.java:54)
```

Comment: Absent Lucene jar or multiple versions of Lucene in the project?

Comment: if one of the answers provided solves your problem, please accept it to close the issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use Elasticsearch and Lucene in your project as separate libraries.

Elastissearch 1.4.1 is based on Lucene 4.10.2. You can check the release blog page [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-4-1-released/) for more details.

To solve your problem you will need to update your Lucene library version to 4.10 and use 
Version.LUCENE_CURRENT instead of LUCENE_3_6.

You can find [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/overview-summary.html) Lucene 4.10 Core API documentation.

I hope that this will help. Don't hesitate to comment if you have doubts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This really works. And, there is no solution to this problem other than this post. Could you also tell me why the latest version does not work with v 1.5 for elastic search?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer elasticsearch v1.5 questions yet. It's been released very recently and I haven't taken a look on it yet. Try to verify what version of lucene the latest version of Elasticsearch uses.

Answer (score 2):

Same error can occur in another case also - if someone unpack new ElasticSearch version in the same directory as previous version. 
Then it ends up with **two versions of the jars in 'ElasticSearch/lib' directory**. The error appears on startup.

In this case, the fix is to make clean ElasticSearch installation, without leftovers.

Answer (score 0):

From ES 7.0 You can check version of Lucene in
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/f2987b417f4346846d50e12b782fb12e153aa4ef/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/Version.java