# Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_3_6

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I am running 1.7.2 elasticsearch server and I'm using org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-groovy:1.7.2 client to connect to it using TransportClient.
elasticsearch-groovy comes with elasticseach 1.7.2 and lucene 4.10.4 dependecy. When the TransportClient object is initialized the following error is thrown "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_3_6". I couldn't find a solution for this and currently I'm stuck. I would be very thankful for any hint.
This is my code:

```
ImmutableSettings.Builder builder = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
builder.put("cluster.name", CLUSTER_NAME).put("client.transport.sniff", true)
Settings settings = builder.build()
client = new TransportClient(settings)

client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300))
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(tenant,table,id)
indexRequest.source(putJsonDocument(documentTitle,description, documentContent, postDate, author))
client.index(indexRequest)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309354/elastic-search-lucene-version-error

Comment: Thanks, but i saw this post already. I didn't understand how the guy set lucene version.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a library conflict.

Do a "gradle dependencies" or it's equivalent mvn command and look for lucence library clashes.

For me it turned out that spring elastic search was colliding with hibernate search