# Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearchHelper'

Tags: grails, elasticsearch

Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearchHelper': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticSearchClient' while setting bean property 'elasticSearchClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearchClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_3_6

1. i am using grails 2.5 and plugin elasticsearch:0.0.3.6'

Comment: Did looking for this exeption in google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309354/elastic-search-lucene-version-error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279924/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-lucene-3-6

Comment: yeah! but those suggesstions arent working for me