# Erro: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_5_2_1

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch, lucene, logstash

Am trying to Index to elastic search using java API and later use that data for visualisation in Kibana as below:

```
package elasticSearchTest;

import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.jsonBuilder;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ES_Test_Class {
  @Test
  public void f() {
  try{
      Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
               .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));


      IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                            .startObject()
                                .field("user", "kimchy")
                                .field("postDate", "18/May/2011:01:48:10")
                                .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                            .endObject()
                          )
                .get();
    // Document ID (generated or not)
      String _id = response.getId();
    // Version (if it's the first time you index this document, you will get: 1)
    long _version = response.getVersion();

    System.out.println("Document id is: "+_id);

    System.out.println("Document version is: "+_version);
      }
      catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
}
```

Below are the updated dependencies:

[image]

However when I run the code I get below error:

> [TestNG] Running:
>     C:\Users\vinbhask\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--931338640\testng-customsuite.xml
>   Nov 04, 2016 9:03:52 PM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService 
>   INFO: [Kismet] modules [], plugins [], sites []
>   FAILED: f
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_5_2_1
>       at org.elasticsearch.Version.(Version.java:265)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:129)
>       at elasticSearchTest.ES_Test_Class.f(ES_Test_Class.java:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)

I tried googling for the solution and came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309354/elastic-search-lucene-version-error) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279924/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-lucene-3-6?noredirect=1&lq=1) but could not understand how to resolve the issue, I had even rebuilt the project by adding one JAR at a time but of no help

[Update]:
After adding lucene 5.5.2 jar getting below error:

> [TestNG] Running:
>     C:\Users\vinbhask\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--545647994\testng-customsuite.xml
>   Nov 06, 2016 9:18:20 AM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService 
>   INFO: [Locus] modules [], plugins [], sites []
>   FAILED: f
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.(Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;I)V
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.createClientBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:354)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:290)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:68)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:182)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:68)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:162)
>       at elasticSearchTest.ES_Test_Class.f(ES_Test_Class.java:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)

Comment: Also having this issue do to a library being used in my project.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Lucene 4.10.4, but Elasticsearch 2.4.1 is based on Lucene 5.5.2. Upgrade your Lucene version ([5.5.2 is here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/java/5.5.2)).