# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.Version

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying out elasticsearch 2.1.1 Java API with ESserver 2.1.0. When i try to create a transport client i see this error and i dont see a reason for this. Along with this i also see the following error

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_4_0_0

Client:

```
  Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
            .build();

    Client client = null;
    try {
        client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), Integer.getInteger(port)));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elastic Search Lucene version error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309354/elastic-search-lucene-version-error)

Comment: I have tried the above solution but the error still persists. The solution described in above post doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full stack trace?